# Put an existing title on a line on several lines

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help ! :/ I have equipment and on some equipment I have sizes. And  Title it's in DESIGN 5 and DESIGN6 but DESIGN5 AND DESIGN6 is located in MOTCLE=CODPRO, DESIGN5 AND DESIGN6 not located in activle with size and in my request I need article with size and the title, I show you an exemple in exel:

Before :

[image]

ABYSS is the hat items and ABYSS39 is the items with size (39 is the size)

After :

[image]

Where there is no design5 and design 6, do not pay attention.

Comment: Please, provide ([why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and [how?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) the following things: 1. All the source data in text format. 2. Result data. 3. Algorithm to transform source to target in readable format (also where new columns came from and on what criteria), i.e. how to get the single example result row from single source row (or group of source rows). Also it will be very good to post your code that you already composed so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to rewrie yor request:
Row CODPRO = MOTCLE includes design 5 and 6 - You want to take this design descrition and populate it to rows with same MOTCLE but different CODPRO - CODPRO+Number and remove redundant CODPRO=MOTCLE row

If there is only one row with MOTCLE - show this row no matter that CODPRO=MOTCLE

If this is the case /at least what I can understant from screenshot examples/ please try this code:

```
select * from (
select e.codpro, e.motcle, max(design5) over (partition by  motcle) as new_design5,
max(e.design6) over (partition by e.motcle) as new_design6,
case
    when (count(*) over (partition by e.motcle) > 1 and e.codpro = motcle) then 0 else 1 end is_visible

from eq e) where is_visible = 1;
```

Please comment.

Thanks.

Comment: THANK you so much you are the best ! you are the community thank you ! you are solve my problems

Comment: @julienlecat - Glad to help. Please mark this answer as Problem solving one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(design5) over (partition by codpro, codcle) as imputed_design5,
       max(design6) over (partition by codpro, codcle) as imputed_design6
from t
```